# How can I configure a Slim application to use a custom request object?

Tags: php, slim

I'm trying to figure out if I can create a custom `$request` object in Slim 3, with some of my own custom methods. I saw https://github.com/slimphp/Slim/issues/1480 through which I wrote:

```
'settings' => [
    'request' => function ($c) {
        return \App\Request::createFromEnvironment($c['environment']);
    },
]

$app = new \Slim\App($settings);
```

Then in my routes:

```
$app->get('/systems', '\App\Controllers\SystemsController:index');
```

But in my controller method, my `$request` object doesn't have any of the methods in my extended function. Not sure what I'm misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `config/container.php`

```
$container = $app->getContainer();

$container['request'] = function ($container) {
    return \App\Request::createFromEnvironment($container['environment']);
};
```